# Show the "trivial bound" $\left|\frac{\log{2}}{\log{3}}-\frac{p}{q}\right|\ge c \frac{1}{2^q}$ holds for $c > 0$ and integers $p, q$ with $q$ positive

Tags: inequality

Given the identities:

1. $3^p - 2^q = 3^p (1 - 3^{q\left(\frac{\log{2}}{\log{3}} - \frac{p}{q}\right)})$ for all integers $p, q$ with $q$ positive.
2. $\left|3^p - 2^q\right| \ge 1$ for all positive integers $p, q$.

Show there exists a constant $c > 0$, such that

$\left|\frac{\log{2}}{\log{3}} - \frac{p}{q}\right| \ge c \frac{1}{2^q}$

for all integers $p, q$ where $q > 0$.

(Paraphrased from **Proposition 5 (Trivial bound)** in [Terence Tao's blog article](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/#ident).)

I assumed it would just involve some algebra, but I couldn't solve it after scribbling a page full of notes.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Changed based on suggestion, but I don't really like how the bar is now broken in the middle.

Comment: Interesting – I don't get a bar broken in the middle here – it looks great now in my browser. Which browser are you using? Anyway, what I mostly meant were the awful tiny parentheses in identity 1.

Comment: I can see how to to obtain the weaker bound $ \frac{c}{q 2^q}$---via a combination of case work and Taylor expansion. Presumably some other insight is needed to remove the extra poly factor.

Comment: @joriki, I'm using Chrome 109.0.5414.87 (arm64) on macOS 13.1. (Updated identity 1 formatting.)